# Ambiguous use of 'initialize()'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using third-party library which is implemented on objective c. I have to develop application in swift.

The library code which I have to use is 'initialize'

```
@interface VidyoClientConnector : NSObject
{}

    +(BOOL) Initialize;
    +(BOOL) SetExperimentalOptions:(const char*)options;
    +(void) Uninitialize;
@end
```

But when using the above's Initialize method I get ambiguous use of

**From swift:**

`VidyoClientConnector.initialize()`

**Exception**

`ViewController.swift:17:9: Ambiguous use of 'initialize()'`

Comment: `+(BOOL) Initialize` That's starting with an uppercase (which is not recommended, I admit), but not with a lowercase.

Comment: When using with cap Xcode gives following 'Initialize()' has been renamed to 'initialize()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both

```
+[VidyoClientConnector Initialize]
```

and

```
+[NSObject initialize]
```

are imported to Swift as `initialize()` class method, and that
causes the ambiguity. Renaming the Objective-C method would be
the best option (but perhaps not possible since it is not your framework).

If you have write access to the headers then you can define a different name for Swift:

```
+(BOOL) Initialize NS_SWIFT_NAME(vidyoInit());
```

which can then be used as

```
let result = VidyoClientConnector.vidyoInit()
```

If you cannot modify the headers then you can implement a wrapper
method in an Objective-C category:

```
// .h file:
@interface VidyoClientConnector (Wrapper)
+(BOOL) vidyoInit;
@end

// .m file:
@implementation VidyoClientConnector (Wrapper)
+(BOOL) vidyoInit { return [self Initialize]; }
@end
```

Finally, in this particular case, you can use that the two methods
have different return values, and resolve the ambiguity with

```
let result = (VidyoClientConnector.initialize as () -> Bool)()
```

without changing any Objective-C code.

Comment: Great! Thanks @Martin